# Mandrill Inbound email- setting up Sending Domains with an app hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, actionmailer, mandrill

I am trying to learn the ins and outs of Mandrill, so I created a test app that has no functionality except creating users, signing them in and out, and clicking on a link that sends the user an e-mail through ActionMailer.

So far all of this works fine. I have configured Mandrill to send e-mail in both development and production (Heroku). What I'm trying to do now is configure it to receive e-mails sent from users and do stuff with them. **My problem is that I'm not sure what to add as my mail domain in the Sending Domains section of my Mandrill account page.**

I've done this before with an app on Heroku using Mailgun. Mailgun gave me a Mailgun subdomain to use for user testing off the bat (app12345678.mailgun.org). I was able to send mail to postmaster@app12345678.mailgun.org and it worked perfectly. With Mandrill it's proven a bit more difficult.

Mandrill doesn't seem to provide a Mandrill subdomain to start with. I suppose my question is: **is it at all possible to get a Mandrill subdomain for testing like the one Mailgun provides? If not, how can I go about user testing inbound e-mail with Mandrill if I don't currently own my own custom domain? What can I use as the Sending Domain?**

Answer (score 0):

it's not currently possible to use Mandrill's inbound email routing unless you have a domain/subdomain to work with. We don't provide a testing subdomain to use for inbound routing.

Any domains you actually send from in Mandrill will be added to the Sending Domains page. You don't have to manually enter any domains there, since we'll detect any that you use and show them there automatically. If you want to set up SPF and DKIM for your sending domain, you can manually add it in order to validate the records have been added correctly.

If you have other questions specific to your account, our support team is also happy to help if you want to get in touch via the Support button in your account.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have taken care of the domain thing. Now I'm finding it impossible to have my route/webhook URL verified, so I guess I'll send in a support request.